# How to sculpt a High Poly Mesh in Detail?

Tags: sculpting, resolution

I'm having an issue with high poly sculpting in blender.

Here's my mesh. As you can see, it's composed of 11M polygons, which is quite a lot.

[image: Raptor mesh]

The thing is, when I want to sculpt little details, I'm limited by the size of my polygons. I'll exagerate it in order to show you.

[image: detail screenshot head]

But when I look at tutorials online, there seems to be no problem with polygons at all :

[image: screenshot from tutorial?]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 11 Million polygons is pretty much at the top end of modelling. I wonder how you've even come so far. Is this model an imported lopoly model?

Comment: Also, take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw32i2dBfEo It shows how to go past dynamic topology and do even more detail without losing too much performance. If you are starting, I recommend looking at dynamic topology. Good luck with your project and I hope I helped

Comment: No, I made this from scratch. It's just subdivided a lot and I sculpted it without dyntopo. I'm kinda new to this, so I'll do as the tutorial Bigfoot posted says.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable Dyntopo(it is in the toolbar) and set it to a high detail. I would search for a tutorial on its use. Hope this helps

Comment: Enabling dynamic topology on a model with 11 Million polygons doesn't make any sense. He needs to start with a model that has much, MUCH lower polycount, otherwise switching to dyntopo effectively doubles them due to triangulation.